# php json_decode is failing with test json

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON.  It validates, but won't decode using PHP json_decode.  Any ideas where to begin?

```
[  
   {  
      "Borrower":" SystemDisc ",
      "Title / Type / Term Votes":"Business+personal - max 5% total Loan type: Business 20.00000000 BTC for 180 days paid every 30 days 20",
      "Country % Funded":" ",
      "Invested Date Listed Reputation":"24% funded",
      "":" 2014-10-11 14:07 CDT",
      "":"100.00 % positive +49, 0"
   },
   {  
      "Borrower":" vitobeta ",
      "Title / Type / Term Votes":"Bitfinex loan #2 - 4-5% monthly Loan type: Investing 3000.00 USD for 180 days paid every 30 days 16",
      "Country % Funded":" ",
      "Invested Date Listed Reputation":"76.7% funded",
      "":" 2014-10-05 13:47 CDT",
      "":"100.00 % positive +225, 0"
   },
   {  
      "Borrower":" joenobody211 ",
      "Title / Type / Term Votes":"Restructure Plan pt1 24% Loan type: Debt Consolidation 8.45000000 BTC for 180 days paid every 30 days 13",
      "Country % Funded":" ",
      "Invested Date Listed Reputation":"26% funded",
      "":" 2014-10-16 18:05 CDT",
      "":"100.00 % positive +294, 0"
   },
   {  
      "Borrower":" TexasKEK ",
      "Title / Type / Term Votes":"30 days @ 15% or less Loan type: Business 1000.00 USD for 30 days paid every 30 days 13",
      "Country % Funded":" ",
      "Invested Date Listed Reputation":"56% funded",
      "":" 2014-10-02 04:44 CDT",
      "":"100.00 % positive +82, 0"
   },
   {  
      "Borrower":" bitcoin24 ",
      "Title / Type / Term Votes":"Website Upgrade [max 15%] Loan type: Investing 1.50000000 BTC for 90 days paid every 30 days 11",
      "Country % Funded":" ",
      "Invested Date Listed Reputation":"23.7% funded",
      "":" 2014-10-14 07:24 CDT",
      "":"100.00 % positive +71, 0"
   },
   {  
      "Borrower":" canhada ",
      "Title / Type / Term Votes":"# 1 investment in gawminner p... Loan type: Investing 6.50000000 BTC for 120 days paid every 14 days 11",
      "Country % Funded":" ",
      "Invested Date Listed Reputation":"21.4% funded",
      "":" 2014-10-08 16:01 CDT",
      "":"100.00 % positive +84, 0"
   },
   {  
      "Borrower":" Mrocean ",
      "Title / Type / Term Votes":"Buying Equity stocks, little ... Loan type: Business 12.00000000 BTC for 60 days paid every 14 days 8",
      "Country % Funded":" ",
      "Invested Date Listed Reputation":"100% funded",
      "":" 2014-10-20 03:44 CDT",
      "":"100.00 % positive +397, 0"
   },
   {  
      "Borrower":" reasilvabr ",
      "Title / Type / Term Votes":"Coffeebit.io 15/35 Loan type: Business 5.00000000 BTC for 360 days paid every 30 days 8",
      "Country % Funded":" ",
      "Invested Date Listed Reputation":"25.7% funded",
      "":" 2014-10-15 11:16 CDT",
      "":"100.00 % positive +234, 0"
   },
   {  
      "Borrower":" mattthebat ",
      "Title / Type / Term Votes":"Investing up to 20% Loan type: Investing 400.00 USD for 30 days paid every 30 days 8",
      "Country % Funded":" ",
      "Invested Date Listed Reputation":"19% funded",
      "":" 2014-10-07 05:15 CDT",
      "":"100.00 % positive +20, 0"
   },
   {  
      "Borrower":" Ohotenco ",
      "Title / Type / Term Votes":"Loan for 2 weeks Loan type: Other 0.27000000 BTC for 14 days paid every 7 days 7",
      "Country % Funded":" ",
      "Invested Date Listed Reputation":"67.9% funded",
      "":" 2014-10-17 16:13 CDT",
      "":"0 % positive +0, 0"
   }
]
```

Comment: Everything seems fine to me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ny40zW You do however have a blank key in each object (`..."":" 2014-10-11 14:07 CDT"...`) which might cause issues. Edit: multiple keys in each object that are blank. They overwrite on the print_r output. `..."":" 2014-10-11 14:07 CDT","":"100.00 % positive +49, 0"...`

Comment: If it still doesn't work for you, try turning error reporting on and/or checking your web server error logs. If there was actually an error, it would write to the error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine if you code it correctly

```
<?php
$t = '[ {"Borrower":" SystemDisc ","Title / Type / Term Votes":"Business+personal - max 5% total Loan type: Business 20.00000000 BTC for 180 days paid every 30 days 20","Country % Funded":" ","Invested Date Listed Reputation":"24% funded","":" 2014-10-11 14:07 CDT","":"100.00 % positive +49, 0"},
        {"Borrower":" vitobeta ","Title / Type / Term Votes":"Bitfinex loan #2 - 4-5% monthly Loan type: Investing 3000.00 USD for 180 days paid every 30 days 16","Country % Funded":" ","Invested Date Listed Reputation":"76.7% funded","":" 2014-10-05 13:47 CDT","":"100.00 % positive +225, 0"},
        {"Borrower":" joenobody211 ","Title / Type / Term Votes":"Restructure Plan pt1 24% Loan type: Debt Consolidation 8.45000000 BTC for 180 days paid every 30 days 13","Country % Funded":" ","Invested Date Listed Reputation":"26% funded","":" 2014-10-16 18:05 CDT","":"100.00 % positive +294, 0"},
        {"Borrower":" TexasKEK ","Title / Type / Term Votes":"30 days @ 15% or less Loan type: Business 1000.00 USD for 30 days paid every 30 days 13","Country % Funded":" ","Invested Date Listed Reputation":"56% funded","":" 2014-10-02 04:44 CDT","":"100.00 % positive +82, 0"},
        {"Borrower":" bitcoin24 ","Title / Type / Term Votes":"Website Upgrade [max 15%] Loan type: Investing 1.50000000 BTC for 90 days paid every 30 days 11","Country % Funded":" ","Invested Date Listed Reputation":"23.7% funded","":" 2014-10-14 07:24 CDT","":"100.00 % positive +71, 0"},
        {"Borrower":" canhada ","Title / Type / Term Votes":"# 1 investment in gawminner p... Loan type: Investing 6.50000000 BTC for 120 days paid every 14 days 11","Country % Funded":" ","Invested Date Listed Reputation":"21.4% funded","":" 2014-10-08 16:01 CDT","":"100.00 % positive +84, 0"},
        {"Borrower":" Mrocean ","Title / Type / Term Votes":"Buying Equity stocks, little ... Loan type: Business 12.00000000 BTC for 60 days paid every 14 days 8","Country % Funded":" ","Invested Date Listed Reputation":"100% funded","":" 2014-10-20 03:44 CDT","":"100.00 % positive +397, 0"},
        {"Borrower":" reasilvabr ","Title / Type / Term Votes":"Coffeebit.io 15/35 Loan type: Business 5.00000000 BTC for 360 days paid every 30 days 8","Country % Funded":" ","Invested Date Listed Reputation":"25.7% funded","":" 2014-10-15 11:16 CDT","":"100.00 % positive +234, 0"},
        {"Borrower":" mattthebat ","Title / Type / Term Votes":"Investing up to 20% Loan type: Investing 400.00 USD for 30 days paid every 30 days 8","Country % Funded":" ","Invested Date Listed Reputation":"19% funded","":" 2014-10-07 05:15 CDT","":"100.00 % positive +20, 0"},
        {"Borrower":" Ohotenco ","Title / Type / Term Votes":"Loan for 2 weeks Loan type: Other 0.27000000 BTC for 14 days paid every 7 days 7","Country % Funded":" ","Invested Date Listed Reputation":"67.9% funded","":" 2014-10-17 16:13 CDT","":"0 % positive +0, 0"}]';


print_r(json_decode($t));
```

Gives a perfectly good array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Borrower] =>  SystemDisc
            [Title / Type / Term Votes] => Business+personal - max 5% total Loan type: Business 20.00000000 BTC for 180 days paid every 30 days 20
            [Country % Funded] =>
            [Invested Date Listed Reputation] => 24% funded
            [_empty_] => 100.00 % positive +49, 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Borrower] =>  vitobeta
            [Title / Type / Term Votes] => Bitfinex loan #2 - 4-5% monthly Loan type: Investing 3000.00 USD for 180 days paid every 30 days 16
            [Country % Funded] =>
            [Invested Date Listed Reputation] => 76.7% funded
            [_empty_] => 100.00 % positive +225, 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Borrower] =>  joenobody211
            [Title / Type / Term Votes] => Restructure Plan pt1 24% Loan type: Debt Consolidation 8.45000000 BTC for 180 days paid every 30 days 13
            [Country % Funded] =>
            [Invested Date Listed Reputation] => 26% funded
            [_empty_] => 100.00 % positive +294, 0
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Borrower] =>  TexasKEK
            [Title / Type / Term Votes] => 30 days @ 15% or less Loan type: Business 1000.00 USD for 30 days paid every 30 days 13
            [Country % Funded] =>
            [Invested Date Listed Reputation] => 56% funded
            [_empty_] => 100.00 % positive +82, 0
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Borrower] =>  bitcoin24
            [Title / Type / Term Votes] => Website Upgrade [max 15%] Loan type: Investing 1.50000000 BTC for 90 days paid every 30 days 11
            [Country % Funded] =>
            [Invested Date Listed Reputation] => 23.7% funded
            [_empty_] => 100.00 % positive +71, 0
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Borrower] =>  canhada
            [Title / Type / Term Votes] => # 1 investment in gawminner p... Loan type: Investing 6.50000000 BTC for 120 days paid every 14 days 11
            [Country % Funded] =>
            [Invested Date Listed Reputation] => 21.4% funded
            [_empty_] => 100.00 % positive +84, 0
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Borrower] =>  Mrocean
            [Title / Type / Term Votes] => Buying Equity stocks, little ... Loan type: Business 12.00000000 BTC for 60 days paid every 14 days 8
            [Country % Funded] =>
            [Invested Date Listed Reputation] => 100% funded
            [_empty_] => 100.00 % positive +397, 0
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Borrower] =>  reasilvabr
            [Title / Type / Term Votes] => Coffeebit.io 15/35 Loan type: Business 5.00000000 BTC for 360 days paid every 30 days 8
            [Country % Funded] =>
            [Invested Date Listed Reputation] => 25.7% funded
            [_empty_] => 100.00 % positive +234, 0
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Borrower] =>  mattthebat
            [Title / Type / Term Votes] => Investing up to 20% Loan type: Investing 400.00 USD for 30 days paid every 30 days 8
            [Country % Funded] =>
            [Invested Date Listed Reputation] => 19% funded
            [_empty_] => 100.00 % positive +20, 0
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Borrower] =>  Ohotenco
            [Title / Type / Term Votes] => Loan for 2 weeks Loan type: Other 0.27000000 BTC for 14 days paid every 7 days 7
            [Country % Funded] =>
            [Invested Date Listed Reputation] => 67.9% funded
            [_empty_] => 0 % positive +0, 0
        )

)
```

Although I didn't know it was legal to have an empty field name of i.e. `""`, but that appears to be converted to `_empty_`

However, I would suggest that whoever came up with the field naming convention needs to have another try at sensible field names, just to make using this data structure a little easier to code and understand.